# Unexpected Output of Shell Script

Tags: linux, shell, sh

I was going through old tutorials and I found one shell script:

```
a=10
b=20
if  $a -eq $b 
then
   echo "a is equal to b"
else
   echo "a is not equal to b"
fi
```

When I stored this shell script as test.sh and executed it. It gives me below output

```
test.sh: 3: test.sh: 10: not found
a is not equal to b
```

I don't understand the first line of the output. I would appreciate if anyone can throw light on what's going on.

Comment: The Internet is full of incompetent shell scripting tutorials. Find a different one. The Stack Overflow [bash tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info) has a reading list, though it is understandably geared towards Bash, not `sh`. Many things work the same, anyway, and a good tutorial should explain the differences, and teach you both portable shell programming and Bash specifics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `if` expects a test, like this: `[ $a -eq $b ]` or `[[ $a -eq $b ]]`.

Your sample expands to: `if 10 -eq 20` at which point bash looks for a program called `10` which obviously doesn't exist, hence the error message.

A missing program apparently evaluates as `false` which leads to the execution of the `else` statement.

Comment: When Bash tries to execute a program that doesn't exist, it returns an exit status of 127. Like all non-zero exit codes, this is considered by the shell to be `false`.

Comment: `if` does not expect a test; it just expects a valid command. `test` (and its unfortunate alias `[`) is just one such valid command, albeit the one the OP wants.